# How many roots are rational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> If $P(x) = x^3 + x^2 + x + \frac{1}{3}$, how many roots are rational?

**EDIT:**

$3x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1 = 0$, if any rat roots then,

$x = \pm \frac{1}{1, 3} = \frac{-1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}$, and none of these work. Complete?

Comment: [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and if necessary [Quadratic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula).

Comment: The only real solution is $x = \dfrac{2^{1/3}-2^{2/3}-1}{3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $3P(x) = 3x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1$ has integer coefficients. So, if $p/q$ with $\operatorname{gcd}(p,q) = 1$ is a rational root, necessary $p$ divides the constant term $1$, and $q$ divides the dominant coefficient $3$. So we have four candidates $-1$, $-1/3$, $1/3$ and $1/3$. Clearly, the roots of $P(x)$ are negative, so we just have to test $-1$ and $-1/3$. The polynomial $P(x)$ has no rational roots.

Comment: There are also the candidates $-1$ and $+1$, but they are no roots either.

Comment: Yes, I've just noticed my oversight.

Answer (score 1):

There's none, the proof is basically the same as for $\sqrt 2$ being irrational. Assume that $x=p/q$ where $p/q$ is can't be reduced further. Now

$$ x^3 + x^2 + x + 1/3 = p^3/q^3 + p^2/q^2 + p/q + 1/3 = 0$$

Multiply both sides with $3q^3$:

$$ 3p^3 + 3p^2q + 3pq^2 + q^3 = 0$$

Now we see that $3|q$ so we rewrite $q = 3r$:

$$ 3p^3 + 3p^23r + 3p9r^2 + 27r^3 = 3p^3 + 9p^2r + 27pr^2 + 27r^3 = 0$$

Now divide by $3$:

$$ p^3 + 3p^2r+9pr^2 + 9r^3 = 0$$

So also $3|p$ wich contradicts the assumtion.